# Let X be a finite set with lXl=6. Then the number of equivalence relations on X such that each equivalence class has at least three elements in it is?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let X be a finite set with |X| : 6. Then the number of equivalence relations on X
such that each equivalence class has at least three elements in it is:
(A) 10.
(B) 11.
(c) 20.
(D) 21.

My try

We know there is a one to one correspondence between Equivalence Relation and Partitions.
Thus, for any equivalence Relation such that each class has at least three elements in it implies the partition of 6 can be either

6 = 2+2+2 or 6 = 2+4 or 6=6.

(Since the partition involving 1 is a one element class.)

The number of ways to partition 6 into 2+2+2 = (6C2 x 4C2 x 2C2)/3! = 15

The number of ways to partition 6 into 2+4 = 6C2 = 15

The number of ways to partition 6 into 6 = 1

Thus , total equivalence Relation such that each class has at least three elements = 15+15+1 = 31

Please correct me where I have made wrong assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the $2+2+2$ case, each equivalence class has two elements and therefore **not** "at least three". A similar thing is true for $4+2$.

There are only two ways to do it. Either $6=6$ or $6=3+3$. Any other partition of $6$ necessarily has either a $2$ or a $1$ and is therefore invalid.

Comment: Yeah... Well I counted the number of relations to be atleast 3. Thank you.